# Count number of files with specific extension(s) for each subdirectory

Tags: command-line, scripts

Source: Any directory tree with any number and type of files. Q: How many `.jpg` or `.jpg` and `.png` (for example) are in each subdirectory?

How can I limit the code below for files with 1 or more specific extension(s)? Having trouble inserting the `-type f -name "*.jpg*"`, for example.

```
for DIR in $(find . -maxdepth 99 -type d)
do
    printf "%10d\t%s\n" $(find ${DIR}|wc -l) "${DIR}" 
done
```

Desired output:

```
118   ./aaa
 73   ./aaa/bbb
 16   ./aaa/bbb/ccc
```

If more than one file types are counted, then their combined total number in each subdirectories should be displayed.

Comment: Do you want combine the result of `.jpg` and `.png` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably this `find`|`xargs` solution will work as you need.

```bash
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 99 -type d -print0 | \
xargs -0 -i bash -c 'printf "%10d\t%s\n" "$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype awk -iregex ".*\.(jpg|jpeg|png)" | wc -l)" "$1"' - '{}'
```

Some explanations:

- The `-mindepth 1` option is added in order to skip the current directory and process only the sub directories.
- The `-print0` provides the output entries with null delimiter, it works together with the `-0` option of `xargs`.
- The option `- "{}"` at the end will pass the `xargs` argument as value of the first positional parameter `$1` of the bash command.
- Within the second `find` command `-iregex` means case insensitive regular expression (you could use `-regex` instead).

Comment: elegant! is there a easy way to suppress listing those subdirs where the count= 0? (e.g., no files matching the `*\.(jpg|jpeg|png)"`).

Comment: Hi, @user3026965, the most easiest way to suppress these lines is by adding `| grep -Pv '^\s+0'` at the end of the command. The option `-P` enables the extended regular expressions, `-v` suppress the matched lines and the regex itself means a line which starts `^` with one or more `+` whitespaces `\s` followed by `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's from mine, modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15221702/12289283).

```
find . -maxdepth 100 -type d -print0 | while read -d '' -r dir; do count=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) -ls | wc -l); printf "%5d %s\n" "$count" "$dir"; done
```

Return this on my test directory.

```
20 .
11 ./level2
3 ./level2/level3
```

Where the content is:

```
$ tree -L 3 level1/
level1/
├── 1.png
├── 10.png
├── 11.png
├── 12.png
├── 13.png
├── 14.png
├── 15.png
├── 16.jpg
├── 17.jpg
├── 18.jpg
├── 19.jpg
├── 2.png
├── 20.jpg
├── 3.png
├── 4.png
├── 5.png
├── 6.png
├── 7.png
├── 8.png
├── 9.png
└── level2
    ├── 20.jpg
    ├── 21.jpg
    ├── 22.jpg
    ├── 23.jpg
    ├── 24.jpg
    ├── 25.jpg
    ├── 26.png
    ├── 27.png
    ├── 28.png
    ├── 29.png
    ├── 30.png
    └── level3
        ├── bull_city.png
        ├── man_city.png
        └── newyork_city.png

2 directories, 34 files
```

---

Just realized you only need sub directories printed.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 100 -type d -print0 | while read -d '' -r dir; do count=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) -ls | wc -l); printf "%5d %s\n" "$count" "$dir"; done
```

Return this.

```
11 ./level2
3 ./level2/level3
```

Answer (score 2):

Find has logical operators like AND, NOT and OR.

To specify more than one extension to search for you need to put the arguments in parentheses, as well as escape the parentheses to avoid them being processed by bash:

```
find . \( -type f -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" \)
```